# How to fix: SELECT element only returns the first option's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

So I have this select element that I use with datatables.js. I insert it per row (inside of a div). Here's how it looks:

[image]

Whenever i try to use jQuery to extract that Select element's current value, it only returns the first option's value even if I change the selection.

I tried different approach on how to insert the div and select element. First is the documented approach in the datatables site using the format(e) function they have. And now the row.push approach but still has the same result.

```
HTML
<table style="width:100%;" id="table_openRequest" class="table dt-responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline collapsed" ></table>

function updateStatus(itemID){

   var jobOrder = itemID;
   alert($('#project-status-' + jobOrder).val());

}

DATATABLES INITIALIZE:
var myTABLE1 = $('#table_openRequest').DataTable( {

   data: null,
   paging: true,
   order: [ 5 , "desc" ],
   pageLength: 100,
   //scrollX: "100%",
   responsive: true,
   language:{
   "paginate": {
      "previous": "<",
      "next":">"
   }
   },
   select: true,
   columns: [
      { title: "", "orderable": false}, 
      { title: "Job Order #:"},
      { title: "Project Title:"},
      { title: "Requested by:"},
      { title: "Status:"},
      { title: "Created:"},
      { title: "", 'className': 'none'}
],
});

INSERT DATA AND DIV IN DATATABLE ROWS:
BU_demand();
function BU_demand() {
    //BU_demand
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
        "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Intake_BUdemand')/items?$select=*,Author,Author/Title,Author/Name,Editor,Editor/Title,Editor/Name&$expand=AttachmentFiles,Author,Editor&$orderby= ID desc&$top=5000";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
               var obj = data.d.results[i];

               var dateRequested = moment(obj.Created).format('YYYY/MM/DD  HH:MM:SS')
               var jobOrder = obj.ID;
               var projectTitle = obj.Project_Title;
               var requestedBy = obj.Author.Title;
               var status = obj.Status;
               var modifiedTime = moment(obj.Modified).format('YYYY/MM/DD  HH:MM:SS');
               var modifiedBy = obj.Editor.Title;
               console.log(modifiedBy);

               var row = [];

               row.push('');
               row.push('<span style="color:blue;" class="span-jobOrder">' + jobOrder + '</span>');
               row.push(projectTitle);
               row.push(requestedBy);
               row.push(status);
               row.push(dateRequested);
               row.push(
                  `<div class="expand-container container" id="expand-${jobOrder}" style="min-width:500px;">

                     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <label for="project-status" style="margin:0px; font-size:16px;">Status:</label>
                        <select name="test" class="custom-select form-input" id="project-status-${jobOrder}" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:10px; height:22px;">
                           <option value="">Select Project Status</option>
                           <option value="Set Appointment">Set Appointment</option>
                           <option value="Interview BA">Interview BA</option>
                           <option value="SOW In Progress">SOW In Progress</option>
                           <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                           <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                           <button type="button" id="btn-openRequest-${jobOrder}" class="btn btn-success" onclick="updateStatus(${jobOrder});" style="border-radius:0px !important; padding: 0px; margin-left:15px; min-width:50px !important;">OK</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                           <label for="" style="margin:0px; font-size:16px;">Last Updated: </label>
                           <span style="margin-left:15px;">Modified by ${modifiedBy} ${modifiedTime} </span>
                     </div>

                  </div>`
                  );

               myTABLE1.row.add(row).draw();

            }
        },
        error: function(e) {}
    })
}
```

Comment: You're not showing the relevant piece of code. You can remove all the code you posted and replace it by the single line that is trying to read the selected value.

Comment: Sorry about that, i forgot about that piece. I added it on the top of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works using vanilla Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

jQuery version:

```js
$('#select').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

So your code should be working, the error must be somewhere else. Are you sure you don't have a duplicate `id` issue here? You cannot have more than one element per page with any given `id` value.

If you have let's say two elements with `id="foo"` on a page, `$('#foo')` **will always only return the first one**:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" value="firstOne" />
<input id="foo" value="secondOne" />
<button onclick="console.log($('#foo').val());" type="button">Log $('#foo').val()</button>
```

`id`is short for **identifier**, which means that it must uniquely point to exactly one element.